# Splitting a string with multiple delimiters in Python

Tags: python, string, split, delimiter

I'm using regular expressions to split a string using multiple delimiters. But if two of my delimiters occur next to each other in the string, it puts an empty string in the resulting list. For example:

```
re.split(',|;', "This,is;a,;string")
```

Results in

```
['This', 'is', 'a', '', 'string']
```

Is there any way to avoid getting `''` in my list without adding `,;` as a delimiter?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
re.split(r'[,;]+', 'This,is;a,;string')
> ['This', 'is', 'a', 'string']
```

Comment: Hmm, okay. Now what if one of my delimiters was also a word? For example: `re.split(',|;|string', "This,is;a,;string")`

Comment: Then this would work: `re.split(r'[,;]+|string', 'This,is;a,;string')`

Comment: Now the output would be `['This', 'is', 'a', '', '']`

Comment: That's normal, you're using multiple separators. If you need to filter empty strings then do this: `[s for s in re.split(r'[,;]+|string', 'This,is;a,;string') if s]`