# Spliting strings surrounded by special characters

Tags: python, regex, list, split

I have an input that looks like the following.

```
word1-word2
word1 word2
word1+word2
--word1--word2-
word1-word2 
word1,word2,
(word1),word2
```

etc

I have to create a list that finally has ['word1','word2']
and nothing else in it. (It can have blanks that I can remove later I guess). There can be any special characters around the two words. Is there any straight forward way to do it? (a better regex??).

I am trying something in the following lines from the following link

[Splitting a string with multiple delimiters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393157/splitting-a-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python)

```
re.split(r'[-+ ,]+', INPUT)
```

There isn't any consistency between special characters surrounding the two words.

Comment: Why don't you just strip the empty strings from the result.

Comment: I have mentioned that I the question.. It can have blanks that I can remove later I guess)

Comment: @simonzack Did I get downvoted for this??

Comment: So is the code you have now not working? Or not straightforward enough? Or what?

Comment: @Ank Yes I thought it was a rather trivial question, if you want to do this using a single `split` you should've said so in the question.

Comment: I was looking for a way in which I don't have to add all the special characters I can think of. Can I tell python (exclude every special character that you see surrounding the words).

Comment: By the definition of splitting, your fourth example has to be split into `['', 'word1', 'word2', '']`. So the only way I can see around it is (a) don't use `split` (e.g., reverse your test and use `findall`), or (b) use `split` and then post-process to strip any "extra" empties off the ends.

Comment: yes.. My code does strip the extra empties in post-process.

Comment: @Ank: So to clarify, your problem was "how to I match all 'special characters' in a regular expression"? If so, edit the question to make that clearer—and also define what you mean by "special characters", because it's hard to guess whether you mean the exact same thing as `\W` or something different…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like what you're really trying to do is extract words from a string that may contain special characters. So just look for words then:

```
re.findall(r'\w+', text)

>>> re.findall(r'\w+', "word1,word2,")
['word1', 'word2']
>>> re.findall(r'\w+', "(word1),word2")
['word1', 'word2']
>>> re.findall(r'\w+', "--word1--word2-")
['word1', 'word2']
```

`re.findall` will create a list of regex matches.

`\w` in regex is a special shorthand for all alphanumeric characters **along with underscore** (equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`). So a caveat with this solution is that if you have something like `word1_word2`, you'll get `['word1_word2']`.

If this is not desired, then go with the following regex: `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

Comment: Why the extra brackets?

Comment: This would be better with an explanation: why using `\w` is better than "trying to name every special character I can think of", and why using `findall` to find words instead of `split` to split on non-words solves the problems with the extra blank values before and/or after the useful ones.

Comment: Ah, because my initial answer was something like `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. Just forgot to remove them.